# js. var или let?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, различия 'var' и 'let' знаю)

Зашел в спецификацию, там написано красным 'Draft'. [image: Скриншот]
Сразу я подумал что нужно выкинуть var и пользоваться исключительно let. И у себя везде где мог заменил.

но когда я зашел на let - я увидел то же самое.. [image: Скриншот]. Скажите пожалуйста, где достоверно, что выкинуть, а что оставить?

P.S. Поддержка старых браузеров не нужна. let трудностей не приносит. Большое спасибо

Comment: let еще многие не поддерживают, я использую только в node.js, пока что.

Comment: Эм-м, а ничего, что `var` на вашем же скриншоте имеется ещё в трёх спецификациях со статусом *Standard*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это норма! В данный момент спецификации 2015 года по let и var являются принятыми стандартами, а аналогичные спецификации 2017 года ещё разрабатываются и находятся в состоянии черновика (draft).

Таким образом, вы можете использовать функционал, описанный в спецификациях 2015 года, но пока не можете использовать то, что появляется только в 2017 году (вероятно, в этом списке есть let expressions и let blocks)

Comment: Добавлю: можно все, если у вас есть [babel](https://babeljs.io/) :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov не стесняйтесь добавлять прямо в ответ )

Comment: Да тут не дописывать надо, а исправлять. Потому что, на самом деле, не так важен факт принятия стандарта - как список поддерживающих браузеров.

Comment: @PavelMayorov сделал общим. Если можете исправить — буду рад.

Comment: забавно, на картинках, пропущена седьмая редакция, которая уже вышла

Comment: когда кодил на бейбел какая-то хрень вместо кода стала.